# Floating point errors

Tags: java, floating-point, rational-numbers

I am having trouble with floating points. A the double . 56 in Java, for example, might actually be stored as .56000...1.

I am trying to convert a decimal to a fraction. I tried to do this using continued fractions

[Continuous Fractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843649/continuous-fractions/21843876#21843876)

but my answers using that method were inaccurate due to how to computer stored and rounded decimals.

I tried an alternative method:

```
public static Rational rationalize(double a){
        if(a>= 1){
        //throw some exception
    }
    String copOut = Double.toString(a);

    int counter = 0;
    System.out.println(a);
    while(a%1 != 0 && counter < copOut.length() - 2){
        a *= 10;
        counter++;
    }
    long deno = (long)Math.pow(10,counter);//sets the denominator
    Rational frac = new Rational((long)a,deno)//the unsimplified rational number
    long gcd = frac.gcd();
    long fnum = frac.getNumer();//gets the numerator 
    long fden = frac.getDenom();//gets the denominator
    frac = new Rational(fnum/gcd, fden/gcd);
    return frac;    
}
```

I am using the string to find the length of the decimal to determine how many time I should multiply by 10. I later truncate the decimal. This gets me the right answer, but it does not feel like the right approach?
Can someone suggest the 'correct' way to do this?

Comment: The first problem here is that the *input* is `double.` So you're already losing precision before any of your code even executes. Have a think about `BigDecimal.`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are doing great.. But this will fail if the Input is something about `11.56`. Here you need to to do `copOut.length() - 3`.

To make it dynamic use `String#split()`

```
String decLength = copOut.split("\\.")[1]; //this will result "56" (Actual string after decimal)
```

Now you just need to do only

```
while(a%1 != 0 && counter < decLength.length()){
        a *= 10;
        counter++;
    }
```

If you want to remove the loop then use

```
long d = (long)Math.pow(10,decLength.length());
 a=a*d;
```